# Does MQ on sender channel side validates the certificates of MQ on receiver channel's side?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jms, ibm-mq

In MQ we have sender channel and receiver channel.

Communication is started by sender channel and only receiver channel has SSLCAUTH attribute

So does certificate of RECEIVER channel MQ is validated by SENDER side or only certificate of SENDER channel MQ is validated by RECEIVER side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue manager initiating the connection always validates the cert presented by the other queue manager as long as the `SSLCIPH` attribute is populated. The cert presented must be trusted and not expired.

On the receiving queue manager the sending queue manager cert is always validated if present. Having `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` and/or a value specified in the `SSLPEER` mandate that the sending queue manager **MUST** have a certificate.

In a TLS session the initiator is the TLS client.  A MQ sender channel is always the TLS client.   The `SSLCAUTH` attribute stands for SSL Client Auth, by setting this to `REQUIRED` you tell the receiver that the sender must have a cert.  Having a `SSLPEER` in the receiver also behaves the same in that it requires the sender to have a cert.

Comment: So SSLAUTH and SSLPEER attribute in RECEIVER makes validating certificate from SENDER mandatory .... And SSLCIPH in SENDER makes validating certificate from RECEIVER mandatory ... Is it this way?

Comment: The sender always validates the cert of the receiver, when you have SSL/TLS enabled.

Comment: `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` or a non-blank `SSLPEER`.

Comment: @JoshMc those are for ssl client authentication, and in this case the client is the sender channel, so the cert of the receiver is always validated no matter the ssl client auth setting.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi that is correct. I stated "The queue manager initiating the connection always validates the cert presented by the other queue manager as long as the SSLCIPH attribute is populated."